# What book is JK Rowling referring to in this line in the credits to "The Christmas Pig"?

Tags: jk-rowling, the-christmas-pig

In The Christmas Pig, JK Rowling writes this in the acknowledgments:

> Without  Fiona  Shapcott,  Di  Brooks,  Angela  Milne,  and  Simon Brown, I’d probably still be writing the last book but one. Thank you for everything you do.

Which books is she referring to?

Answer (score 5):

She appears to be referring to *[Troubled Blood](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Troubled_Blood)*, the fifth in her series of Cormoran Strike novels written under the pseudonym of Robert Galbraith. It was, quite literally, her last but one book to be published.

[image]

Also, her [acknowledgments](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=bYXQDwAAQBAJ&pg=PT889&lpg=PT889&dq=%22to%20William%20Leone%20and%20Lynne%20Corbett%20for%20inspiration%20and%20for%20checking%20my%20calculations%22&source=bl&ots=yCgjFwETWk&sig=ACfU3U206BgwxOyXHtuA_fCFFod7vmopJg&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwijnp3bivH2AhUsQkEAHYR-CzoQ6AF6BAgCEAM#v=onepage&q=%22to%20William%20Leone%20and%20Lynne%20Corbett%20for%20inspiration%20and%20for%20checking%20my%20calculations%22&f=false) in the book itself contain a very similar list of individuals.

> ACKNOWLEDGEMENTS
> My thanks, as ever, to my superb editor David
> Shelley, who always makes the job a pleasure; to my wonderful agent
> Neil Blair; to the management team who keep me sane, Mark Hutchinson,
> Rebecca Salt and Nicky Stonehill; to my home and office team, without
> whom this book would never have been finished: **Di Brooks**, **Simon Brown**,
> Danny Cameron, **Angela Milne**, Ross Milne, **Fi Shapcott** and Kaisa
> Tiensuu; to Neil Murray, the world’s best reader of works-in-
> progress; to Kenzie, for spotting that cross of the Knights of St John
> where I didn’t expect to find one; to William Leone and Lynne Corbett,
> for inspiration and for checking my calculations; to Russell Townsend,
> for helping me check out all these locations and for saving my dead
> laptop; and to Tom Burke, for fascinating Crowleyana and the Atlantis
> bookshop.

---

As to who these individual are,

> **Fi Shapcott** was originally employed as nanny to J. K. Rowling’s
> children and has worked for them for 16 years. As the children have
> matured, she has spent some time working in the Edinburgh office for 2
> to 3 days per week in addition to her childcare duties.
>
> **Di Brooks** is the manager of J. K. Rowling’s office in Edinburgh. She has worked for Rowling for many years 14-16 years as of 2018.
>
> **Angela Milne** is the secretary to J. K. Rowling; she has worked nearly 16 years and is based at the Edinburgh office. Her job is to respond to emails and fan letters and to organise responses to sick children.
>
> **Simon Brown** is J. K. Rowling’s personal assistant dealing with her personal (non-business) organisation and needs.
>
> <sub><sup>Troubled Blood: The Acknowledgments - https://www.hogwartsprofessor.com/</sup></sub>